# Do I need to backup a database after an upgrade?

Tags: django, database, postgresql

I am using python and Django for my project. I have upgraded PostgreSQL version from 9.6 to 10. Before that, I made a backup of my database.

```
./manage.py dumpdata > db.json
```

After a successful upgrade, I had no idea whether the database will intact. But upon checking, I found the database was okay. I think it is necessary to backup before an upgrade, but do I need (or recommended) to load the backup data back to the cluster again? Or is there any recommended way of upgrading the database.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you should make a backup before upgrading as you said.

And you can make a backup after an upgrade too.

It depends on the database. If you're just making a backup of the data and any version of database can restore it. then you don't really need to have a backup after upgrading.

But if you're backup can't be restored from any other versions or it needs some extra work for it, then having a backup can save a lot of time for you.

In general, a backup from data can be used anywhere and you can import it to any database. But making a backup after an upgrade wont really hurt anyone. So why not? There might be some problems that you didn't consider or you can even make a full backup of your entire database settings before and after so you can make sure if anything came up, then you have the settings that you know it works.